# После запроса на изменение данные не меняются, хотя все переменные передаются

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
    $a=$_POST['sex'];
    $b=$_POST['position'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "library");
    $mysqli->query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $name = explode('/', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])[2];
    $person = $_POST['person'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
        $mysqli->query ("UPDATE `person` SET `Full_name` ='$person', `Phone_number` ='$number', `Sex` = '$a', `Position_ID` ='$b', WHERE `person`.`ID` ='$name'");
    $mysqli->close ();
    require('tablperson.php');
?>
```

Comment: Привет, SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

if ( !isset($number) ) { и.д...

Comment: ошибка была в запятой перед WHERE